# Drop observations that belong to a range of values

Tags: r

My data frame has one variable "zip code" that contains 60 different zip codes.

I want to drop all observations that have a specific zip code such as 38004,38014,38027,38049,38083, etc (20 zip codes I want to drop in total).

How I can use subset or droplevels() with this?

Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a vector of zip codes and use `%in%` with negate (`!`)

```
v1 <- c(38004, 38014, 38027, 38049, 38083)
df2 <- subset(df1, !`zip codes` %in% v1)
```

If `zip codes` is factor, convert to `character`

```
df2 <- subset(df1, !as.character(`zip codes`) %in% v1)
```

Comment: I tried! but when i checked again ii still see all the zip codes! `v <- c("38004","38014","38027","38049","38083","38124","38130",
       "38137","38139","38168","38173","38174","38177","38182",
       "38183","38184","38186","38187","38190","38194")

read2 <- subset(read1, !`zip` %in% v)`

Comment: @AnnNg You need to assign it to an object as in `df2 <-` and then check df2

Comment: @AnnNg Do you have those elements already in 'read1' 'zip' column.  Is it a `factor` or `character` column?

Comment: oh never mind, i use factor() after subsetting and it works now! thank you!

Comment: @AnnNg if it is to drop the levels, just do `df2 <- droplevels(df2)`

Comment: hi. I tried `df2 <- subset(df1, !as.character(`zip`) %in% v1)`, but it did not work. What works is `v1 <- c(38004, 38014, 38027, 38049, 38083)
df2 <- subset(df1, !`zip` %in% v1) df2$zip <- factor(df2$zip)`. So I partially applied what you advised! Thank you much!

Comment: @AnnNg it is always better to show the `dput` as the type may matter.  If it works, please do consider to accept solution .thanks